# Merging results from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I will try and set the scene as best i can. ***lights candle**

What i am trying to acheive is this

1. Search `image_likes` to see if the user has liked any images and then include them in next query.
2. Grab all images from `images` that user has uploaded.
3. Show both results aswell as ORDER BY `id` DESC.

I am horrible at MySQL when it comes to including different table results, so i hope i have included enough information. Let me know if you need anymore.

**Table Structures**

`image_likes`

id | user_id | image_id

`images`

id | uploader_id | date

Comment: Unless you have a very strange table structure, this should be doable with a single `joined` query: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: What would really be helpful is the code you've already tried, and what the result was

Comment: @orourkek I have not tried but rather researched. And their are so many different types of joins i had no idea where to start.

Comment: @MarcB Which type? Inner Join?

Comment: Edited with table structures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1:

```
SELECT * FROM Image_Likes WHERE User_Id = x ORDER BY Id DESC
```

2:

```
SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Uploader_Id = x ORDER BY Id DESC
```

3: (all together)

```
SELECT L.*, I.* FROM Image_Likes L LEFT JOIN Images I ON L.Image_id = I.Id WHERE L.User_ID = x  ORDER BY I.Id DESC
```

Replace x with the User's ID

Comment: Just to clarify, does this select and search all the `image_likes` results from `images`?

Comment: And also, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN Images I ON L.Image_id = I.Id ORDER BY I.Id DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1 :(

Comment: Yes! It takes all of the results from the first bit (any matches on ID from Image_Likes) and attempts to JOIN them with a corresponding value from the Images table (ON l.image_id = I.id)

Comment: Sorry, fixed order of the WHERE. Try it now

Comment: It seems to only be bringing back image_likes results from `images` rather than the results AND the users uploads. Ill do some more testing.

Comment: Sorry, try it once more. Added the I.* - it's getting late ;)

Comment: Still not working grabbing the users uploads :S. Wouldnt their need to be another query to find all the uploads by the user, ontop of searching for their liked images info?

Comment: Completely misread your question. Sorry! (I have all images that the user liked AND uploaded)

Comment: Haha, i see. basically its for a activity stream that will show all the uploads by the user and images they have liked on their profile. Hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you should really try to get a grasp on JOINs. you will continually write bad code, and design bad databases to work around not knowing how to use them.

```
SELECT *
FROM images
LEFT JOIN image_likes ON image_likes.image_id = images.id
WHERE image_likes.user_id = $my_id
OR images.creator_id = $my_id
ORDER BY images.id DESC
```

Comment: The code isnt working as intended.It is including other peoples likes if it is the current users uploads. I will play around with it

Comment: @Trendee if im not mistaken, i believe you can add an AND to the ON clause, to add a `image_likes.user_id = $my_id`